# How can I use css properties with different classes?

Tags: html, css

I have different css classes based on different actions. Everything is working good, but when I apply `activeBackground` class based on condition its making div `background-color` to green but `border-left-color` is not coming green its still using `.arrow-div` class. How can I resolve this issue and apply `.activebackground` class when needed?

HTML

```
<div class="text-arrow" ng-class="{'activeBackground': applyActiveFile, 'completeBackground':applyComplete}">File Selection
  <span class="arrow-div"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text-arrow {
    background-color:#BABABA;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:45px;
}
.arrow-div {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0.15em;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;    /* Use font-size to control the size of the arrow. */
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    background-color:#fff;   /* change background color acc to bg color */ 
    border-left-width: 0.2em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #BABABA;
    left:0.25em;
}
.activeBackground{
     background-color: green;
     border-left-color: green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to me that you're applying `.arrow-div` and `.activeBackground` to different elements, and the way your code is written, `.activeBackground` can't override `.arrow-div` because it's being applied to a different element (the parent). To affect the child element (the span containing the arrow) you need to set up a css rule that directly targets any child `.arrow-div` of `.activeBackground`.

My solution was to simply modify your css like so, providing a way to change the arrow div:

```
.activeBackground{
    background-color: green;
}
.activeBackground .arrow-div{
    border-left-color: green;
}
```

Here's a fiddle of it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/cupno5g9/

Comment: This is basically div with arrow at the end so arrow is not getting the color i want to apply same color to div and arrow

Comment: Once I loaded it in a fiddle, I realized what you were doing. Give the updated answer a whirl :)